Import shapefile using ogr2ogr with a subselect to fill a constraint fails to "cannot open datasource"
I try to import various shapefiles into a postgis database. The shapefiles have some foreign keys referencing other existing (and already successfully imported) tables.
ogr2ogr -f "$($json.ogr_format)" PG:"host=$($json.db_host) user=$($json.db_user) dbname=$($json.db_name) password=$($json.db_password)" `
       -unsetFid `
       "$shapefile" -nln existing_schema.destination_table -nlt POLYGON `
       -sql "SELECT (SELECT id FROM existing_schema.source_table t WHERE t.objectid=field_in_shape) as fk_column, [...] FROM $shapename" `
       -dialect sqlite `
       -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco SCHEMA=existing_schema `
       -append `
       -progress

The error i get is ERROR 1: Cannot open datasource 'existing_schema'
I tried with and without -lco SCHEMA which makes no difference.
I tried omitting the schema in the query itself like but then I get no such table: source_table.
I tried using " around the schema and source-table independently (like "SELECT (SELECT id FROM ""existing_schema"".""existing_table"" t WHERE t.objectid=field_in_shape) as fk_column, [...] FROM $shapename") with no success.
Other script without subselects are working as intended. All tables and columns do exist.
Using ogrinfo like
ogrinfo -ro PG:"host=$($json.db_host) user=$($json.db_user) dbname=$($json.db_name) password=$($json.db_password)" `
 -sql "SELECT id from existing_table where id = '09409423-f786-4a74-8708-d75b604cce1e'" `
 -oo ACTIVE_SCHEMA=existing_schema `
 -dialect sqlite

looks successful?
INFO: Open of `PG:host=localhost user=postgres dbname=postgres password=XXXXXX'
      using driver `PostgreSQL' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
id: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  id (String) = 09409423-f786-4a74-8708-d75b604cce1e

Can someone point me in the right direction? What am I missing?
Edit: as user30184 mentioned i tried changing the SQL to a join instead of a subselect, but the error is still the same:
-sql "SELECT [fields_in_shape], g.id FROM $shapename f LEFT JOIN existing_schema.existing_table g on f.fk_field = g.field_identifier" `

I get no SQL syntax errors. Still unsuccessful "cannot open datasource: existing_schema".

If you are on Windows this escaping shoud work SELECT id FROM \"existing_schema\".\"source_table" t 

Sadly no success. The escaping seems to work but the error remains the same.

Are you really reading shapefiles?  And the query should combine a shapefile that you want to import with a field from an existing PostGIS table? In that case I think you should use JOIN https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html#joins. However, that gets complicated with the ogr2ogr command line. I think I would import the whole shapefile into a temporary PostGIS table and do the SQL things in the database.

I might have overlooked the "joins". thank you for the hint, i will try that. And yes I have valid shapes (viewable through qgis, esri and geoserver), which now shall be in a postgis database for further "enhancement". The advice importing temporary was in my mind too. Using ogr2ogr and specify the contents of the resulting layer via sql seemed to me as the preferred way. I will play around and might fall back to your suggestion. thank you!
